# Ground extraction from laz

Tags: filter, laz, pmf

I have got laz file without classification[image]

However everything what I can extract with pdal is this:
[image]

Seems like the algorithm detects everything as ground. The code is following:

```
pipeline = [
"/home/input.laz",
{   
    "type":"filters.pmf",
    "returns":"first"
},
"/home/output.laz"
]


 import pdal
 import json
 import numpy as np
 pipeline = pdal.Pipeline(json.dumps(pipeline))
 pipeline.validate()
 count = pipeline.execute()
```

I tried different filters, however no positive result. Another question is why 'return' condition works only with 'first' and returns **RuntimeError: filters.pmf: No returns to process.** in any other case

P.S. https://pdal.io/tutorial/ground-filters.html - this solution worked in my case. Now I have segmented ground and unclassified stuff. The problem was in deleting classified *.laz* file and *ept* folder every time before I'm trying to do segmentation.  However problem with 'returns' still be unclear

Comment: Not an answer, however, if nothing else works another option for identifying those returns that lie on the probable ground surface (bare-earth points) is FUSION/LDV: Software for LIDAR Data Analysis and Visualization GroundFilter tool ( http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/fusion/fusion_overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

The reason I have 'first' returns workable is because my file only contains it.

There is more info here: https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/issues/3463